# Adding border-right: 1px causes the whole structure to fall apart

Tags: css, border

How would this be fixed so that ‘border-right: 1px’ can be used?

```
border-right: 0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7dj6crmL/30/

```
input[type=submit] {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

[image]

`border-right: 1px` **Added In**:

https://jsfiddle.net/7dj6crmL/32/

```
input[type=submit] {
  border-right: 1px solid #0059dd;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move ***container-right*** before ***container-left*** and change CSS class as follows:

`.container-right {
  float: right;
}`

note: margin on container-right is not needed anymore

https://jsfiddle.net/4rz6tjg0/